# How to get a Spotify Access Token for my discord music bot - discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, api, discord.js, authorization, spotify

I made a Music Discord Bot for my server and I want to get some information about songs using the spotify-web-api, but I don't really know how to get an access token for my application. Im really new to node.js and I hope someone can help me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js nor discord.js. It is completely related to spotify.

Get more information about creating an app and get your client secret here:
 https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/app-settings/

Comment: Thank you that helped me